# Is this an open set in $(C([0,1]), \left\|{\cdot}\right\|_p)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\{g\in C([0,1]):\int_{0}^{1}|g(x)|dx<1\}$. If $p\in [0,\infty]$, is $A$ an open set of $(C([0,1]), \left\|{\cdot}\right\|_p)$?

Is it obvious that if $p=1$ then $A$ is open in $(C([0,1]), \left\|{\cdot}\right\|_1)$, because $A=B(0,1)$.

I think $A$ is not open if $p>1$. Any hint to show this?

Thanks.

Comment: If so, $f: x \mapsto x^p$, from $\|\cdot\|_p$ to $\|\cdot\|_1$ would be a continuous bijection. The open mapping theorem would imply that it is an open mapping. But this cannot be so, since the norms are not equivalent. I am not really confident... am I right?

Comment: @AndréCaldas: You didn't define an _operator_ from $(C[0,1],\Vert\cdot\Vert_p)$ to $(C[0,1],\Vert\cdot\Vert_1)$, you simply defined an element of $C[0,1]$. So the open mapping theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: @J.Loreaux: in this case, $x: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. You are right that it is not a <b>linear</b> operator. Also, I guess it is not a bijection. So, my argument is totally wrong!!! :-)

Comment: @myself: It is a bijection!

Comment: @myself: By the way, $C[0,1]$ with some $p$-norm (not $\infty$) is not Banach! :-P

Comment: ... and open mapping theorem requires completeness ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that from [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), valid for $p \geq 1$,
$$
  \|f\|_1 = \|f \cdot 1\|_1 \leq \|f\|_p \|1\|_q = \|f\|_p,
$$
where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$,
since $\|1\|_q = 1$.

But this implies that the identity
$$
  \begin{array}{rrl}
    \mathrm{id}: &(C([0,1], \|\cdot\|_p) &\rightarrow &(C([0,1], \|\cdot\|_1)
    \\
                 &x &\mapsto &x
  \end{array}
$$
is continuous. And since $A = \mathrm{id}^{-1}(B(0,1))$, and $B(0,1)$ is open in the $1$-norm, it follows that $A$ is open.

---

**Edit:** added observation from Pedro Tamaroff that Hölder is valid for $p \geq 1$.

Comment: (Note Hölder holds for $p\geqslant 1$!)

Comment: @AndréCaldas, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, $A$ is open for $p>1$. Let $g \in A$ and $\varepsilon = \frac12\left(1-\int_0^1|g(x)|dx\right)$. Then for any $f \in C([0,1])$ with $\|f\|_p < \varepsilon$ we have $$\int_0^1|g(x)+f(x)|dx \le \int_0^1|g(x)|dx+\int_0^1|f(x)|dx \le \int_0^1|g(x)|dx+\|f\|_p < 1.$$

Comment: Notice that the key to the argument is the fact that $\|f\|_1 \leq \|f\|_p$.